# VBA code goes into an infinite loop and will then fill-down the entire infinite column

Tags: excel, vba, infinite-loop

I have been dealing with customer bill of materials that contains references with numbers that are separated by a dash, rather than the full sequence of references spelled out, e.g. C1-4 instead of C1, C2, C3, C4 or C1 C2 C3 C4

Some customers will use a comma to separate references, some only a space, sometimes there is a mix of the two. Sometimes customers leave a blank line between sections of references, which also complicates things. Empty cells should remain empty in the output. Here is an example:

```
   CR161-169

 (blank line)
 
   R2, R5, 7-11

   R103-7
   
   R26 R28-30 R42, R45-46, R62-65, R70-71, R92-102, R113-114
   
   R31-35 R40-41 R56-61 R72-79 R86-91

 (blank line)
   
   LED1-4, 6-8
```

I'm trying to make a VBA macro that will generate the full set of references automatically for the selected portion of the references column, and generate that full set of references in the column next to it.

So the output I'm looking for is:

```
CR161 CR162 CR163 CR164 CR165 CR166 CR167 CR168 CR169
(Blank line)
R2 R5 R7 R8 R9 R10 R11
R103 R104 R105 R106 R107
etc.
```

I have run into a couple of (I think related) problems.

1. In the output, any blank lines are not staying blank, they are filled with the references from the cell above it.
2. If I select the entire column, it goes into an infinite loop and fills down the entire column to infinity below the end of the references with the references from the last cell. I tried to stop it from doing that with an End If, but I clearly didn't do that right.

Another issue driving me bonkers is the case of R2, R5, 7-11, it outputs as R2 R5 7 8 9 10 11 instead of with the R prefix. If that can't be fixed, it's acceptable for what I'm doing, but having the prefix in front of each number is preferable.

I am not great with VBA, but I got the below code running without throwing any errors when I only run the macro on a selection of references, aside from the problems I mentioned above. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

```
Sub ParseCell()
' Set the input range where your values are
Dim inputRange As Range, outputCell As Range, inputArea As Range
Dim inputCell As Variant
Dim startNum As Long, endNum As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim resList  As String
Debug.Print "Selection_change"

Set inputRange = Selection ' Use the selected range as input

' Set the output range where you want the split references
Set outputCell = inputRange.Offset(0, 1).Cells(1) ' Output in the column next to the input

    ' Loop through each area in the input range
    resList = ""
    For Each inputArea In inputRange.Areas
        ' Loop through each cell in the area
        For Each inputCell In inputArea
            Set outputCell = inputCell.Offset(0, 1).Cells(1)
            ' Split the value by dash
            Dim parts() As String
            If Len(inputCell.Value) > 0 Then
                resList = ""
            ElseIf Len(inputCell.Value) = 0 Then ' blank cell
                Debug.Print "blank"
                'the same as previous
                'resList = resList
            ElseIf IsEmpty(inputCell) Then
                Debug.Print "empty"
                resList = ""
            End If
            If Len(inputCell.Value) > 0 Then
                parts = Split(Replace(inputCell.Value, ",", " "), " ")
                For i = LBound(parts) To UBound(parts)
                    If Len(Trim(parts(i))) > 0 Then
                        resList = resList & ExpandCellsList(Trim(parts(i))) & " "
                    End If
                Next i
                If Len(resList) > 0 Then resList = Left(resList, Len(resList) - 1)
            End If
            Debug.Print outputCell.Address, resList
            outputCell.Value = resList
        Next inputCell
    Next inputArea
End Sub

Public Function ExpandCellsList(cl As String) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim sH As String, sv1 As String, sv2 As String
Dim startNum As Long, endNum As Long
Dim res As String
    i = InStr(1, cl, "-")
    If i > 0 Then
        sv2 = Trim(Mid(cl, i + 1))
        sH = Trim(Left(cl, i - 1))
        For i = 1 To Len(sH)
            If InStr(1, "01234567890", Mid(sH, i, 1)) > 0 Then
                sv1 = Trim(Mid(sH, i))
                sH = Trim(Left(sH, i - 1))
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If Len(sv2) < Len(sv1) Then
            sv2 = Left(sv1, Len(sv1) - Len(sv2)) & sv2
        End If
        startNum = Val(sv1)
        endNum = Val(sv2)
        If endNum > startNum Then
            For i = startNum To endNum
                res = res & sH & CStr(i) & " "
            Next i
        End If
        If Len(res) > 0 Then res = Left(res, Len(res) - 1)
        ExpandCellsList = res
    Else
        ExpandCellsList = cl
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You should clear `resList` for every cell, and only populate the output cell when `Len(resList)>0`

Comment: `Set inputRange = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` will exclude any cells with no content.  Then in the loop you'd populate `inputCell.Offset(0,1)` with the result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ony some corrections, pls. check. Mark changes and additions.

```
Dim sH As String       'Added
Sub ParseCell()
' Set the input range where your values are
Dim inputRange As Range, outputCell As Range, inputArea As Range
Dim inputCell As Variant
Dim startNum As Long, endNum As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim resList  As String
Debug.Print "Selection_change"

Set inputRange = Selection.Columns(1) ' Added Use the selected range as input

' Set the output range where you want the split references
Set outputCell = inputRange.Offset(0, 1).Cells(1) ' Output in the column next to the input

    ' Loop through each area in the input range
    resList = ""
    For Each inputArea In inputRange.Areas
        ' Loop through each cell in the area
        For Each inputCell In inputArea
            Set outputCell = inputCell.Offset(0, 1).Cells(1)
            ' Split the value by dash
            Dim parts() As String
            If Len(inputCell.Value) > 0 Then
                resList = ""
            ElseIf Len(inputCell.Value) = 0 Then ' blank cell
                Debug.Print "blank"
                'the same as previous
                'resList = resList
            ElseIf IsEmpty(inputCell) Then
                Debug.Print "empty"
                resList = ""
            End If
            If Len(inputCell.Value) > 0 Then
                parts = Split(Replace(inputCell.Value, ",", " "), " ")
                For i = LBound(parts) To UBound(parts)
                    If Len(Trim(parts(i))) > 0 Then
                        resList = resList & ExpandCellsList(Trim(parts(i))) & " "
                    End If
                Next i
                If Len(resList) > 0 Then resList = Left(resList, Len(resList) - 1): outputCell.Value = resList  'Moved here
            End If
            Debug.Print outputCell.Address, resList
        Next inputCell
    Next inputArea
End Sub

Public Function ExpandCellsList(cl As String) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim sv1 As String, sv2 As String, shdepo As String   'Added
Dim startNum As Long, endNum As Long
Dim res As String
    i = InStr(1, cl, "-")
    If i > 0 Then
        sv2 = Trim(Mid(cl, i + 1))
        shdepo = sH
        sH = Trim(Left(cl, i - 1))
        For i = 1 To Len(sH)
            If InStr(1, "01234567890", Mid(sH, i, 1)) > 0 Then
                sv1 = Trim(Mid(sH, i))
                sH = Trim(Left(sH, i - 1))
                If Len(sH) = 0 Then sH = shdepo   'Added
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If Len(sv2) < Len(sv1) Then
            sv2 = Left(sv1, Len(sv1) - Len(sv2)) & sv2
        End If
        startNum = Val(sv1)
        endNum = Val(sv2)
        If endNum > startNum Then
            For i = startNum To endNum
                res = res & sH & CStr(i) & " "
            Next i
        End If
        If Len(res) > 0 Then res = Left(res, Len(res) - 1)
        ExpandCellsList = res
    Else
        sH = Left(Trim(cl), 1)    'Added
        ExpandCellsList = cl
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I tested your code, and your changes work! It now does exactly what I want it to do, thanks very much :)

Comment: Hi Black Cat, I've run into a minor? problem, the code is supposed to wrap text in the output column (which it does) and then resize the height of the cell to contain the new, longer list of references (which it does not).

Comment: @white This is cell format alignment setting.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that without breaking the code, but I will play around with it a bit.

Comment: @white On the worksheet select column B, right click and select `CellFormat`, click `Alignment` tab and there check `Wrap text`

Answer (score -1):

Here the general idea is to first get the letter(s) and work with numbers separately. Then, in the resulting string the letters will be added before the numbers. Let's see how it's done.

First add some references in VB editor. Go to "Tools" - "References" and add these:

- Microsoft Scripting Runtime (for Dictionary, Collection)
- Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 (for RegEx pattern)

The procedure "ConvertReferences" starts with filling the dictionary of separators your clients might use: this could be commas, spaces, semicolons, etc. However not dashes. This is the dictionary named "Replacements".

Next we create a RegEx pattern that matches first letter(s). We store the letter(s) and continue with the numbers.

Now the "ParseOneCell" function is used to run through each cell in the selection. We strip it of spaces, standardize the separators (using "Replacements" dictionary), and using the standard separator (space) we get our array "Arr". The values from "Arr" will be analyzed further down. We'll use the items from this array to fill "Numbaz" collection.

In the "Arr" array we can have 2 cases: 1) numbers with hyphen, 2) single numbers. In case one we'll use "RangeFromNumbers" function to make a nice range of values which we next add to "Numbaz" collection. If this is case 2, we simply dump the number to "Numbaz" collection.

In "RangeFromNumbers" function special care is taken to process shortened numbers, like 7-11, or 103-7. For cases like "7-11" we create a temporary collection of numbers from first to last. For cases like 103-7 we use "GetNumEndFromShortened" function where we convert the numbers to strings, reverse them and obtain 107 as the last number, which is then used in "RangeFromNumbers" to generate the desired range.

Once "Numbaz" gets filled with the range of numbers, we can prefix them with the letter code and thus create the "Result" string.

```
Option Explicit

' Add references
' Tools - References:
' - Microsoft Scripting Runtime
' - Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Public Replacements As Dictionary
Public Numbaz As Collection
Public re1 As RegExp

Sub ParseCellsRange()
    
    Dim RgIn As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ArrOut As Variant
    
    ' Fill the dictionary with all the separators the client might use
    Call FillReplacements
    
    ' Create RegExp pattern
    Set re1 = New RegExp
    With re1
        .Pattern = "[a-zA-Z]+\d?" ' any letters followed by one digit
        .Global = False ' find first
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With
    
    Set RgIn = Selection
    For Each cell In RgIn
        If Trim(cell.Value) <> "" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1) = ParseOneCell(cell.Value)
        End If
    Next cell
    
End Sub

Private Function ParseOneCell(ByVal CellVal As String) As String
    
    Dim s As String
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim ColRange As Collection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Match As Object
    Dim Matches As Object
    Dim MatchVal As String
    Dim LetterCode As String
    Dim Result As String
    
    ' Remove leading/trailing spaces
    s = Trim(CellVal)
    
    ' Standardize separators
    For i = 0 To Replacements.Count - 1
        s = Replace(s, Replacements.Keys(i), Replacements.Items(i))
    Next i
    
    ' Split on spaces
    Arr = Split(s, " ", -1, vbTextCompare)
    
    ' Extract letter code from first item
    Set Matches = re1.Execute(Arr(0))
    For Each Match In Matches
        MatchVal = Match.Value
        LetterCode = Left(MatchVal, Len(MatchVal) - 1)
    Next Match
'    Debug.Print LetterCode
    
    ' Remove letter codes from array items
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Arr(i) = Replace(Arr(i), LetterCode, "", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
    Next i
    
    ' Throw numbers one by one into collection
    Set Numbaz = New Collection
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        If InStr(1, Arr(i), "-", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' Hyphen found: create range
            Set ColRange = RangeFromNumbers(Arr(i))
            For j = 1 To ColRange.Count
                Numbaz.Add CStr(ColRange(j))
            Next j
        Else
            ' arr item is one number, add it
            Numbaz.Add Arr(i)
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Concatenate letter codes & numbers
    Result = ""
    For i = 1 To Numbaz.Count
        Result = Result & LetterCode & Numbaz(i) & " "
    Next i
    
    ParseOneCell = RTrim(Result)
    
End Function

Private Function RangeFromNumbers(ByVal NumsString As String) As Collection
    
    Dim NumStart As Long
    Dim NumEnd As Long
    Dim NumStartStr As String
    Dim NumEndStr As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TwoNums As Variant
    Dim Result As New Collection
    
    TwoNums = Split(NumsString, "-", -1, vbTextCompare)
    NumStart = TwoNums(0)
    NumEnd = TwoNums(1)
    If NumEnd < NumStart Then
        ' Second number is shortened
        NumStartStr = TwoNums(0)
        NumEndStr = TwoNums(1)
        NumEnd = GetNumEndFromShortened(NumStartStr, NumEndStr)
    End If
    For i = NumStart To NumEnd
        Result.Add i
    Next i
    Set RangeFromNumbers = Result
    
End Function

Private Function GetNumEndFromShortened(ByVal Num1 As String, _
        ByVal Num2 As String) As Long
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RevNum1 As String
    Dim RevNum2 As String
    Dim Result As String
    
    RevNum1 = StrReverse(Num1)
    RevNum2 = StrReverse(Num2)
    Result = ""
    
    For i = 1 To Len(RevNum1)
        If i <= Len(RevNum2) Then
            Result = Result & Mid(RevNum2, i, 1)
        Else
            Result = Result & Mid(RevNum1, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    GetNumEndFromShortened = Val(StrReverse(Result))
    
End Function

Private Sub FillReplacements()
    
    Set Replacements = New Dictionary
    
    With Replacements
        .Add ", ", " "
        ' .Add "; ", " "
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I got a compile error "User-defined type not defined" for the line: Public Replacements As dictionary

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).